# How to return the pic from Camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I've the below code, that open the Camera intent and allow me to take a pic, and save it.
In my `Activity layout` I've an image view, how can I program it, so that once the camera capture the pic, the camera intent is closed, return back to my activity, and show the taken pic in the image view?

```xml
// Androidanifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="hasan.tts_mobile">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My code:

```
// MainActivity.kt
package hasan.tts_mobile

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var uri: Uri
    val REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
    lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener {
            if(isPermissionGranted(permission.CAMERA)) startCamera()
            else requestCameraPermission(this)
        }

    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val imageBitmap = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap
            imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
        } 
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,grantResults: IntArray) =
        onPermissionsRequestResult(this@MainActivity,
            requestCode, permissions, grantResults)

}
```

Request for permission:

```
// CameraPermission.kt
object CameraPermission {
    fun requestCameraPermission(activity: AppCompatActivity) {
        Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA permission has NOT been granted. Requesting permission.")
        if (activity.shouldShowPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying audio permission rationale to provide additional context.")
        } else {
                // Audio permission has not been granted yet. Request it directly.
                activity.requestPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_CAMERA)
        }
    }
}
```

Below extensions to simplify requis for permition:

```
// 
fun AppCompatActivity.isPermissionGranted(permission: String) =
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

fun AppCompatActivity.shouldShowPermissionRationale(permission: String) =
    ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)

fun AppCompatActivity.requestPermission(permission: String, requestId: Int) =
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(permission), requestId)
```

Permission Results Listner:

```
// PermissionsRequestResult.kt
package hasan.tts_mobile.permissions

import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.widget.Toast
import hasan.tts_mobile.extensions.containsOnly


const val REQUEST_CAMERA = 0

object PermissionsRequestResult {
    fun onPermissionsRequestResult(context: Context, requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {

        when (requestCode) {
            REQUEST_CAMERA -> if (grantResults.containsOnly(PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    context, "Camera permission is granted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                //   tts = TtsSpeaker(context, context)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    context, "Camera permission NOT granted",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The containsOnly is:

```
// CollectionExt.tk
package hasan.tts_mobile.extensions

fun IntArray.containsOnly(num: Int): Boolean = filter { it == num }.isNotEmpty()
```

The `xml/file_path.xml` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images" path="/Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

And my layout file is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.236"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.904" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="288dp"
        android:layout_height="401dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/pic_desc"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCamera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:text="@string/take_pic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need the taken pic to appear in place of the Android logo in the image view in the activity?

[image]

Comment: check this its provides you standard implementation for handling image capture. https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics

Comment: @karan this is what I follwed

Comment: what is the issue with your implementation? did you check your code on actual device

Comment: @karan, te camera app is not returning the image to my imageview

Comment: did you test this code on actual device.

Comment: @karan no, just the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you no need to ask `CAMERA permission` when you are capturing image using  `Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`

Try this code

> Declare below variables

```
private val CONTENT_REQUEST = 123
private var output: File? = null
var outPutFileUri: Uri? = null
```

> Take picture using below code

```
    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener {
         val fileName = System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpeg"
         output = File(
             mContext?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
             fileName
         )
         val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
         outPutFileUri = mContext?.let { it1 ->
             FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                 it1,
                 BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
                 output!!
             )
         }
         intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outPutFileUri)
         startActivityForResult(intent, CONTENT_REQUEST)
        
    }
```

> set image in your image view using below code

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            userIMG.setImageURI(outPutFileUri)
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

> don't forget to add `provider` inside  `<application` of `manifest` file
>
> you need to add your package name inside `android:authorities="`

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="hasan.tts_mobile"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

OR:
`android:authorities="${applicationId}"`, not `"${applicationId}.fileprovider"` as in the original code

[image]

Comment: What is `rootView`

Comment: @HasanAYousef ignore `rootView` i have used that code inside fragment that's why i have added `rootView` please check updated answer

Comment: I got: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority hasan.tts_mobile`

Comment: @HasanAYousef check updated answer i have added `provider` class

Comment: I do have it in Manifest file, kindly see the code in my question, where is my mistake?

Comment: @HasanAYousef  please don't use `val imageBitmap = data!!.extras!!.get("data") as Bitmap` because it returns the thumbnail of the image not the actual image that you have captured using the camera you should use 'Uri' as suggested in my answer , rest is your choice

Comment: I just noticed the pic is rotated by 90 degree in the imageview comparing to what is was in real?

Answer (score 0):

In onActivityResult()

```
val imgUri = data?.data
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri)
```

if using glide

```
Glide.with(this).load(imgUri).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder).into(this)
```

Comment: Not getting what do you mean by using `Glide....`, whee shall I use it?

Comment: Means if you are using Glide library for image loading then you can use it.
or if you are not using any image loading library then  use 

val imgUri = data?.data
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri)

Comment: I'm not using any library, I used your code, but did not work also :(